# Android - Window Flags

Tags: android

Is there a way to detect when a window flag triggered? Let's just say I have a `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE`. How do I detect it when I triggered it? I tried googling the problem but all I've got are just setting/adding the window flags. Thanks!

Comment: If you'd like to detect this from the command line after the APK is already built, you can see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45946681/2291928

Answer (score 3):

In your activity simply override `onWindowAttributesChanged`, in Kotlin:

```
class MyActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    private var lastKnownWindowFlags = 0

    override fun onWindowAttributesChanged(params: WindowManager.LayoutParams) {
        if (params.flags != lastKnownWindowFlags) {
            // New window flags!
            lastKnownWindowFlags = params.flags
        }
    }
}
```