# How to query FLAG_SECURE from current APK screen via command line?

Tags: android, adb

How can I query against the current window/activity of an android app to check [window flag](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE) FLAG_SECURE? Is this possible using ADB or any other command line tool against an APK?

My use case is: I would like to query the device to see if FLAG_SECURE is enabled on the current screen. I do not have access to source code, I am just working with an APK as a black box acceptance tester.

Note that this other question is similar and unanswered: [Android - Window Flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35283197/android-window-flags)

Comment: I would imagine that it is in `adb shell dumpsys` output somewhere. Finding where it is, and parsing that output to determine it programmatically, will be a chore.

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried your advice but unfortunately, throughout the entire dumpsys output, there is no difference between a page that is FLAG_SECURE vs not.

Comment: That's surprising. But, in that case, I suspect that you are out of luck.

Comment: Actually @CommonsWare, upon further investigation of a simpler example (Secure and Not Secure sample at https://github.com/gwpantazes/Flag-Secure-Sample/releases), I did find the SurfaceFlinger service which shows whether the current screen is Secure (secureVis=0 or 1). Since you helped me find the answer, would you like to write something up and get the accepted answer?
Via command line, The user can run `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger | grep secureVis | tr "," "\n" | tr -s ' ' | grep "secureVis" | cut -d"=" -f2` and get a boolean of whether the secure flag is set for the current screen.

Comment: I recommend that you answer your own question, explaining what you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out if some specific window has the `FLAG_SECURE` set by just checking `mAttr` line in the `dumpsys window <window id>` output:

```
~$ dumpsys window com.android.settings | grep '   mAttrs='
    mAttrs=WM.LayoutParams{(0,0)(fillxfill) sim=#20 ty=1 fl=#85810100 pfl=0x20000 wanim=0x103046a vsysui=0x700 needsMenuKey=2}
```

The `fl=` value is the `WindowManager.LayoutParams().flags` of that window in hex. `FLAG_SECURE` is a bitmask with the value of `0x2000`. This is how you can check it right in the `adb shell`:

```
for f in $(dumpsys window com.android.settings | grep '   mAttrs=' | grep -o ' fl=#[^ ]*'); do [[ $((16#${f#*#}&8192)) -ne 0 ]] && echo 'FLAG_SECURE is set' || echo 'FLAG_SECURE is not set'; done
```

Answer (score 3):

Whether or not any secure layers are currently visible regardless of the specific window can be found by running this command:

```
adb shell "dumpsys SurfaceFlinger | grep -o secureVis=. | cut -d= -f2"
```

which will return the value of `0` for *no secure layers visible*, or `1` for *some secure layers are visible*.

`isSecure` may seem like the more appropriate value, but it is not. It always shows `1` for some reason, possibly just saying that the device supports secure pages in general.

Comment: SecureLayer visibility flag has been removed from SurfaceFlinger dumpsys output https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/native/+/b5b3563%5E!/